# How to prove that $y = 0,273273273...,$ is a rational number?

Tags: rational-numbers

How to prove that $$y = 0.273273273...$$ is a rational number?

I don't have any experience with proofs... Can I get your help and your advice?

Comment: compute $\frac{273}{999}$

Comment: You could start by observing that its $273\times0.001001001001...$, and that $999\times0.001001001...=0.9999....=1$.

Comment: what's your definition of a rational?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $y$ has a repeating cycle of $3$ digits, just write: $\;1000y=273+y$, solve for $y$, and simplify.

This procedure, though intuitively clear, is not rigourously justified, but it can easily be justified with the interpretation of the positional notation for numbers via a geometric series.

Comment: Thank you Bernard and all!

Answer (score 6):

$1000y = 273.273273...$. Therefore, $1000y-y = 273$. Solving for $y$, $y = \frac{273}{999}$.